# Cakephp: Ajax response is not correctly in "edit"

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an ajax code, that, when change the select value, load the values of the next select.

When I'm in some page, exemple: `societario/attorneys/solicitar` this works fine and load the `loadfiliais`fine.`

But, when I'm in `societario/attorneys/edit/` for exemple, the response is the same edit page and don't the loadfiliais view.

The response is OK, but the page is the actual page, `edit`.

[image]

Here is the code of ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.loading').hide();
        $("#AttorneyEmpresa").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { select: $('#AttorneyEmpresa').val()},
                url: 'loadfiliais',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#AttorneyFilial").hide();
                    $('.loading').show();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                     $("#AttorneyFilial").html(data).show();
                     $('.loading').hide();
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

The controller loadfiliais:

```
function loadfiliais() {

    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->loadModel('Branch');

        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->set('filiais',$this->Branch->find('all', array('conditions' => array('company_id' => $this->request->data['select'])))
        );


    }

}
```

The view loadfiliais:

```
<option value="">Selecione</option>
<?php foreach($filiais as $filial): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $filial['Branch']['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $filial['Branch']['nome']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: This should be simple to narrow down where the actual issue is.  Use something like Google Chrome's Developer tools, click the Network tab, and see what URL it's trying to hit, what it's returning...etc.  Then, when you have the details of what's going on, ask a more concise question.

Comment: I told the response is ok. But if put an image anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `loadfiliais` is an action in the `attorneys` controller. In that case the trailing slash will most likely be the problem.

Without the trailing slash, `solicitar` is treated as a filename, and `attorneys` as the folder where the file is located, and that is the base folder for the AJAX call, so you'll end up with `societario/attorneys/loadfiliais`.

With the trailing slash, as in `societario/attorneys/edit/`, `edit` is treated as the base folder, and so you'll end up with an AJAX call to `societario/attorneys/edit/loadfiliais`.

You can avoid this by using an absolute path for the AJAX url, ie

```
url: '/societario/attorneys/loadfiliais'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the pacience and the explanation abou the problem. It works!!! thanksssssss